# NIFI IMAP Consume Processor Issue

Tags: apache-nifi

We are using an IMAP consumer processor in our nifi pipeline to read the email from office 365. We have been observing issues in the IMAP processor while consuming the email from office 365 email box.
Please find the below error log for your references.

```
2021-01-04 11:00:00,286 ERROR [Timer-Driven Process Thread-6] o.a.nifi.processors.email.ConsumeIMAP ConsumeIMAP[id=c31e4176-842d-3464-b870-2460ee675eee] Failed to receive messages from Email server: [javax.mail.MessagingException - A3 BAD Request is throttled. Suggested Backoff Time: 68448 milliseconds
2021-01-04 11:00:00,286 ERROR [Timer-Driven Process Thread-6] o.a.nifi.processors.email.ConsumeIMAP ConsumeIMAP[id=c31e4176-842d-3464-b870-2460ee675eee] Failed to process session due to org.apache.nifi.processor.exception.ProcessException: Failed to receive messages from Email server: [javax.mail.MessagingException - A3 BAD Request is throttled. Suggested Backoff Time: 68448 milliseconds: org.apache.nifi.processor.exception.ProcessException: Failed to receive messages from Email server: [javax.mail.MessagingException - A3 BAD Request is throttled. Suggested Backoff Time: 68448 milliseconds
org.apache.nifi.processor.exception.ProcessException: Failed to receive messages from Email server: [javax.mail.MessagingException - A3 BAD Request is throttled. Suggested Backoff Time: 68448 milliseconds
at org.apache.nifi.processors.email.AbstractEmailProcessor.fillMessageQueueIfNecessary(AbstractEmailProcessor.java:328)
at org.apache.nifi.processors.email.AbstractEmailProcessor.receiveMessage(AbstractEmailProcessor.java:381)
```

Below is the nifi properties:

image.png

Please let us know if we are missing some configuration in the above screenshot.

Thanks and Regards,
IBNEY HASAN

Comment: Please fix the formatting of your post & the upload of your screenshot

Answer (score 1):

This is not an error specific to NiFi - O365 is telling you that you are being throttled. You will need to tune your O365 settings appropriately, which is outside of the scope of NiFi.

See:

1. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/archive/blogs/exchangedev/exchange-online-throttling-and-limits-faq
2. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/mailbox-migration/office-365-migration-best-practices#office-365-throttling

Comment: This could still be a nifi issue,  if the concurrency/run schedule on the Imap processor is 0 (default) it will run constantly.... set the run time to something that doesn't hit o365 throttle like 30 sec, 60 sec.

Comment: True, but we can't see the nifi config to confirm their run schedule - you could also argue that running constantly is desired behaviour (isn't specified in the question, so I can only comment on the specific error, which is an O365 error)